# Is there a way to get the first non-matching character's position after regexec call

Tags: c, regex

In the following oversimplified code sample:

```
reg = "^[0-9]{1,10}$";
str = "123abc";
regcomp(&re, reg, REG_EXTENDED);
regexec(&re, str, 0, NULL, 0);
```

After `regexec` returns `REG_NOMATCH` I want to get the position of the character that caused matching to fail (3 in the example above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is really not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what is the last that fit you need try all combinations that fits:

```
int count=1; 
varReg=strdup("^[0-9]");
while (works(varReg)){
   aux=varReg;
   varReg=malloc(strlen(varReg)+1);
   sprintf(varReg,"%s%d",aux, count++);
   free(aux)
}
fprint ("fail in: %d\n", --count);
```

you need build `bool works (char* regex)` but is easy ;)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I would rather implement my own state machine for the regex - it would be more efficient at least... I am looking for a straightforward way of doing that - next I am going to check if libpcre allows getting such info.

Comment: Also your suggestion may be valid for the simple case above (just sprintf needs "%s{%d}", but imagine that the test regex was a magnitude more complex - its no trivial task to convert a given complex regex into a regex that would match just a prefix from the language of the former one.

Comment: yes, a state machine is how works the regexp.  you can change and make more complicate code  the idea was only make a auto checked, with your data was difficult make any more concrete.  My code only was a example,and have a fail with number over 9 malloc(strlen(varReg)+1); not make the correct reservation, and its make a buffer overflow.